# Can I use side_effect in my mocking to provide an indefinite number of values?

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

So I can use an iterable with side_effect in python mock to produce changing values returned by my calls to the mock:

```
some_mock.side_effect = [1, 2, 3]
```

return_value provides the same value every time

```
some_mock.return_value = 8
```

Is there a way I can use one or both of these methods so that a mock produces some scheduled values to begin and then an infinite response of one particular value when the first set is exhausted? i.e.:

[1, 2, 3, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, etc. etc etc.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific build-in feature that does that, but you can achieve this by adding a side effect that does this.

In the cases I can think of, it would be sufficient to just add some highest needed number of values instead of an infinite number, and use the `side_effect` version that takes a list:

```py
side_effect = [1, 2, 3] + [8] * 100
my_mock.side_effect = side_effect
```

If you really need that infinite number of responses, you can use the other version of `side_effect` instead that uses a function object instead of a list. You need some generator function that creates your infinite list, and iterate over that in your function, remembering the current position. Here is an example implementation for that (using a class to avoid global variables):

```py
from itertools import repeat

class SideEffect:
    def __init__(self):
        self.it = self.generator()  # holds the current iterator

    @staticmethod
    def generator():
        yield from range(1, 4)  # yields 1, 2, 3
        yield from repeat(8)  # yields 8 infinitely

    def side_effect(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return next(self.it)

...
my_mock.side_effect = SideEffect().side_effect
```

This should have the wanted effect.

Comment: Thank you this makes sense.  Benefit to this would be mocking time.time() in unit tests so that they don't have to run forever, particularly when different behavior is being tested at different time intervals.